# Zend PDF Memory Management

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm trying to create a large PDF file using Zend\PDF. But since Zend keeps the data in an object, at some point it shows "memory exhausted" error message.

Does anybody knows how to manage memory while creating large PDF files???

Comment: Is it an idea to write the output in a file using file_put_contents(, FILE_APPEND) and later on load it into a Zend\PDF object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to increase the size limit of the memory temporarily:

```
$memory_berfore = ini_get('memory_limit'); // in your php.ini
// New Limit
ini_set('memory_limit','256M'); //128M, 256M, 512M, 1024M,... (X*2M)
...
your code (creating large PDF)
...
// Older Limit
ini_set('memory_limit',$memory_berfore);
```

**Edit:**
As stated by `pgampe`, you can put `-1` instead of `'256M'` in my example to have no memory limit.

Comment: Yeah thats a way to go, But still we have the limitations right?

Comment: You have the system memory limit.  Can you give me back?

Comment: You can try ``-1`` for infinite.

Comment: @pgampe: Thank's for your return, I up your comment and updtae my answer. :)